# React webpack app public/images vs src/images

Tags: reactjs, webpack, assets, directory-structure, organization

I'm also using webpack to transpile and bundle onto public.
What are the pros and cons of keeping image assets in public vs non-public.
Which project structure is better for a react app?

```
public/  
-images/  
--favicon.ico  
--(other-image-files...)  
-index.html
-bundle.js

src/
-components/
-style/
-images/
-utils/
```

Comment: Nowadays the suggested way to go is to use and follow what create-react-app.

Answer (score 2):

The `src` directory has a long history of source code being compiled, linked, and eventually ending up as an executable. Given today's build tools, that concept is still current. With `webpack`, `brunch`, or `parcel`, you never really "serve" anything directly from a `public` directory - everything is transpiled, bundled, etc. into a `public` or `dist` output directory.

With that in mind, I would submit that `src` is completely appropriate for images and even your `index.html` file (noting that the `index.html` that ends up in your distribution folder is likely different that the original "source" `index.html` that you created). I hope that helps. Not sure if it is *better*, but I offer it as a point of view given your question.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the idea is that images in the public directory are accessible by URL outside your app.  Anything in src will only be built in if you load it through webpack import. I generally keep things in src unless it is publicly shared.

Answer (score -1):

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder

The recommended approach in the CRA docs is to put images in `src` and load it by importing it.

Using `public` folder should be only for exceptional cases.